# What's the reason for "async" in testWidgets methods?

Tags: flutter

Every example I can find of [widget testing](https://flutter.io/testing/#widget-testing) has you write methods with a signature `testWidgets('name of the test', (WidgetTester tester) async`. Is the `async` part always necessary by some requirement of the test framework or only if you're using an `await` or making a Future call somewhere in the method body?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need it whenever you use `pumpWidgets`, which you pretty much always use if you're using `testWidgets`, since that's the point of `testWidgets`.

`pumpWidgets` uses it because that's how the feature that you can run a test using either `flutter test` in accelerated artificial time or `flutter run` in real time is implemented.

Answer (score 0):

`async` is only necessary when `await` is used.

Seems they were a bit eager to add it (or forgot to remove it) even when it wasn't necessary.

Comment: @FrankHarper what part do you think is incorrect? The docs do contain methods where `async` was added even though `await` isn't used - for example `setUp()`.

Comment: @FrankHarper My answer says that `async` is necessary when `await` is used. Ian just explained why they use `await` in almost every test. If `await` is not used, `async` is not necessary. Therefore it's not a requirement of the test framework or similar.